# Vue JS Get value of each radio group

Tags: laravel, vue.js, for-loop, radio-group, inertiajs

Hi Im struggling to get the value of each radio button groups. The functions is about getting answers from different questions.

```
{{form.answer_ids}}

<div v-for="ans in answers" :key="ans.id">
    <div v-if="ans.question_id == question.id">
                                            
       <div class="p-2 border rounded border-secondary m-2" > 
         <input 
           style="cursor:pointer;" 
           class="form-check-input m-2" 
           type="radio" 
           :name="ans.question_id" 
           :value="ans.id" 
           v-model="form.answer_ids"/>
         <h5 class="ml-4 p-1"  v-html="ans.description"> </h5>
       </div>  
           
     </div>                        
</div>

<script>
                                        
 data() {
        return {

            form: this.$inertia.form({
                answer_ids:[]
            }),
 
        }
},
</script>
```

When there is v-model, the radio is not grouping yet returning only 1 value (not array), On the other hand, When I Remove v-model, The grouping is working but unable to get the data.

How can i possibly achieve this? Just taking the checked radio answer ids is enough for me.

Thank you very much and have a good day!

Comment: Pretty sure that you need a common `name` for a radio button. Put something like `name="question"` and a v-model, and it should do it.

Comment: Tried it man but no luck. I agree  with it needs to be in common name but it has to be common name in each group in order to get value in each group. Thanks a lot appreciate it!

Comment: Try to use the vue devtools and don't overcomplicate things at first, do it with a single array, then try to loop with the `answers` !